# Is it possible to add watermark to audio file using java?

Tags: java

I have a application that is ckecking if an audiofile is edited. After that, I should come to know if someone has edited this audio file. I am thinking of adding a water mark to the audio file to later check if the watermark has changed or not and know if audio file was edited.

Also, is there another way for audio edit protection in java?

Comment: Why not just compare the size of the original file with the new one? If its bigger or smaller then it was edited. Or save the date when it was created/uploaded/whatever and compare with the modification date.

Comment: Why not use hashing ?

Comment: Instead of watermarks, compare the checksum.

Comment: thank you so much for rply.. but how can I use check some in audio file and how can I identify audio is edited or not using checksum?

Comment: I have also used checksum but get confused how to work with it?

Comment: how to use hashing in audio? Palcente sir?

Comment: @Unnati I have posted an answer, please have a look

Comment: Did my solution work ? If yes, please accept the answer, if not - let us know, so we can propose an alternative!

Answer (score 2):

There is a method that applies to any file, not just audio.
You can compute and compare checksums using hashing algorithm.

Java has this feature built in in `java.security.MessageDigest` package.

To get the checksum, consider this code snippet:

```
try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

    byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = -1;

    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(bytesBuffer)) != -1) {
        digest.update(bytesBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    byte[] hashedBytes = digest.digest();

    return convertByteArrayToHexString(hashedBytes);
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException ex) {
    throw new HashGenerationException(
            "Could not generate hash from file", ex);
}
```

This method body returns the string representation of Hashed Array of bytes for your input file. You can call this code on the original and suspect files and do the comparison. If strings match, files are identical.

Code snipped uses fast MD5 angorithm, but you can choose something more secure from  [here:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#MessageDigest)